# Number of k-cliques in random graphs is Poisson

Tags: random-graphs

How do I show that number of k-cliques in G(n,p) has a Poisson distribution?

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Do you know how to prove that a distribution is approximately Poisson?

Comment: This strikes me as a question in *mathematics* rather than *computer science*.

Comment: Finally, I'm not sure that the distribution of $k$-cliques in $G(n,p)$ is approximately Poisson for *all* values of $p$.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What have you tried so far?  What is preventing you from making progress on your own?  Where did you run across this exercise?  We're happy to help you understand concepts, but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.  Also, this sounds like a pure math question.  While pure math questions aren't necessarily off-topic on CS.SE, for them to be appropriate here we expect you to explain in the question why this needs to be answered from a CS perspective.  Can you edit the question to address the feedback you've received?